# glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST) - nothing rendered

Tags: opengl

In OpenGL, I display a simple model. When I enable the depth buffer,

```
glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
glDepthMask(GL_TRUE);
```

everything disappears. I read [this](http://www.opengl.org/archives/resources/faq/technical/depthbuffer.htm) OpenGL FAQ, but it didn't help me.

My perspective settings are: `angle=45deg`, `near=1`, `far=40`, I put model at `(0,0,0)` and I place my eye at `(0,0,4)`. Without the Z-buffer, I *can* see the model.

What could be wrong?

Comment: maybe your you render your model on the wrong side? try disabling GL_CULL_FACE. This is just not enough code to say what's wrong.

Comment: Nope, didn't help. What do you mean "wrong side"? That the normals are in opposite direction? I load a standard model from a file. I do not assure any particular order of rendering, but this is z-buffer job, right?

Comment: @JakubM.: Normals don't influence culling. Face culling depends on the direction on screen in which the vertices come in. It's fully configurable, bue default is, to cull faces whose vertices are drawn in clockwise order on screen.

Comment: -1: For not including more complete code, thus forcing people to *guess* at the answer.

Comment: It could be the `winding order` of your vertices if `GL_CULL_FACE` is enabled; and you have to clear the `GL_COLOR_BUFFERT_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)`...

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Did you make sure you clear the depth buffer?

```
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me too.  I had it in the render code, just not while resizing.

Comment: And do not make the mistake of mixing up the above-mentioned #define with this one: GL_DEPTH_BITS  ...which will not work and will leave you very unhappily non-rendering!

Comment: So, is this basically saying "clear the color buffer AND the depth buffer"?

Comment: @JaredBeck: Yes, each bit selects a buffer layer subject to the clearing operation.

Comment: If the above doesn't work, check your near plane in the gluPerspective, glFrustum, or glOrtho function. Depth buffering doesn't seem to work if it is set to 0.

Answer (score 6):

If the other answer does not work, Try what [user886079](https://stackoverflow.com/users/886079/user886079) mentioned in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10042412/glenablegl-depth-test-nothing-rendered/40816523#comment47079174_10043242)

> If the above doesn't work, check your near plane in the gluPerspective, glFrustum, or glOrtho function. Depth buffering doesn't seem to work if it is set to 0.

I had tried almost everything but could not solve the overlapping issue. I had put the near value 0.0f. I changed it to 0.01f and the results now are how it needed to be.

Answer (score 1):

If the following answers above do not work try the following:

- If you have `GL_CULL_FACE` enabled  check the winding order of your model's vertices. `(LH)` vs `(RH)`.
- If `GL_DEPTH_TEST` is enabled; then check the planes to your frustum against your model view projection matrix along with the camera's position & view direction.
- If `GL_BLEND` is enabled; check the rendering order of your objects in comparison to the `z-buffer`.