# glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST) makes nothing but Sky-Sphere Render

Tags: c++, opengl

*Edit: Rendering the skybox before all other objects in the scene fixed this problem.*

I've seen the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10042412/glenablegl-depth-test-nothing-rendered/40816523) but adding

```
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
```

doesn't appear to help.

I'm trying to render a spherical Skybox for my scene and for some reason when I Disable depth testing before doing so, the Skybox is the only thing rendered.

```
[Render other objects..]

// Disable depth test & mask, faceculling
glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST); // Adding this makes everything else invisible
glDepthMask(GL_FALSE);
glCullFace(GL_FRONT);

[Render texture onto inside of sphere..]

// Re-enable faceculling, & depth
glDepthMask(GL_TRUE);
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
glCullFace(GL_BACK);
```

Any idea why this might be happening?

I wasn't sure of what code to include to keep this clear, so don't hesitate to ask for more.

Comment: The following page of this online tutorial might help you: https://learnopengl.com/Advanced-OpenGL/Cubemaps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just to let you know, this:

```
glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
```

Disables both depth test and writing, so you don't need both that and set the depth mask to GL_FALSE.

When you clear the depth buffer each frame by default it should clear it the maximum value, probably 1.0. By default the depth function is GL_LESS meaning any depth value coming out of the fragment shader less than the one in the depth buffer passes and is written to the framebuffer.

It seems to me that what you're doing is clearing the depth buffer to 1.0, disabling depth testing and writing, drawing your objects, then enabling depth testing and writing and drawing your skybox. The problem with this is that the drawing of your objects doesn't write anything to the depth buffer, and so when it comes time to draw your skybox (with depth testing enabled) all the pixel depth values in the buffer are 1.0 (because you never wrote anything to it), and because the depth function is GL_LESS every pixel you draw of your skybox passes the depth test and is written to the framebuffer.

If there is a special need to have your objects always drawn in front of the skybox, for example the skybox follows the camera position around, then:

1) Disable the depth writing.

2) Draw the skybox.

3) Enable the depth writing.

4) Draw your objects.

Comment: My skybox is following the camera around, yes.

Just following your steps (same as mine without disabling depth testing) seems to be making objects with transparent areas render nothing in those areas, rather than the skybox that should be showing through.

Comment: @Torantula No actually your way and my way are opposite, I said to draw the skybox FIRST. If you draw the objects first of course the skybox won't pass the depth test if the objects are closer to the camera. Let's just say you draw a window with 0.5 alpha transparency, the depth buffer will be written as if the window is completely opaque, depth writing doesn't take into account the transparency. It writes that depth value of the window and the skybox (if drawn afterwards) won't pass the depth test. Handling transparency in these situations can be tricky and has no single answer.

Comment: @Torantula, But there are few simple ways to get around it like drawing transparent stuff from farthest to nearest. Still, if you do like I said, draw the skybox FIRST, your transparent objects should still show through to the sky. It's just that if you don't order the drawing properly, or don't handle transparency correctly the transparent parts of your objects will prevent objects behind it from drawing at all.

Comment: Ah, my mistake.Your explanation of how the depth buffer works is very helpful.
Thank you for taking your time to help me out.

Comment: `glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)` is horribly named. No one would expect that to disable both reading a writing.

Answer (score 0):

Well, yes. That's what the depth test is for. Without it, there's nothing to indicate to OpenGL that the skybox *shouldn't* be rendered on top of everything else.

If you don't want this to happen, don't disable the depth test… or draw the skybox before everything else, instead of afterwards.

Comment: Ah, rendering the skybox first fixed the problem, thank you!